# SpringBoot 製 の war を JBoss にデプロイしてセッションレプリケーションしたい

Tags: java, spring

SpringBoot 製 の war を JBoss にデプロイしてセッションレプリケーションしたいのですが方法が解らず困っています。

通常、Java のウェブアプリケーションでセッションレプリケーションしたい場合、web.xml に  を追記する必要があるかと思います。
しかし SpringBoot の場合、web.xml が存在しないため、通常通りに行きません。
なにか方法がないか検索してみたのですが、解らずじまいでした。

SpringMVC などの他のフレームワークで作成したアプリケーションでのセッションレプリケーションは出来ることを確認しております。

やりたいことの前提としましては、下記のとおりです。
・SpringBoot を使いたい。
・アプリケーションサーバは SpringBoot の組み込み Tomcat ではなく、通常の JBoss を使いたい。
・JBoss の機能でセッションレプリケーションしたい。
　他のプロダクト（Hazelcast 等）を使う方法はあまり望んでおりません。

これが可能かどうか、可能であればその方法が知りたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `web.xml`は追加出きるんでしょう？違いますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。そもそも SpringBoot 製 war を JBoss で動かすためには特殊な手順を踏む必要があり、上記条件を採用できないことがわかりました。お手数をお掛けしてすみませんでした。